# How can I filtering a postgres query with multiple selects?

Tags: php, html, filtering, psql

I have 4 selects in my html code and 2 date input.
I want to filter the query so that it doesn't take into account what I didn't select.

for example:

```
<label>Filter 1:</label>
<select id="list" name="list" >
            <option value="null"> </option>
            <option value="opt1">OPT1</option>
            <option value="op2">OPT2</option>
            <option value="op3">OPT3</option>
</select>

<label>Filter 2:</label>
<select id="list2" name="list2" >
            <option value="null"> </option>
            <option value="opt21">OPT21</option>
            <option value="op22">OPT22</option>
            <option value="op23">OPT23</option>
</select>

<label>Filter 3:</label>
<select id="list3" name="list3" >
            <option value="null"> </option>
            <option value="opt31">OPT31</option>
            <option value="op32">OPT32</option>
            <option value="op33">OPT33</option>
</select>


...
```

So if I select something in Filter 1 and 2 but nothing in Filter 3 I want the query to appear accordingly.

I've tried with "OR" and "AND" in query, but not working perfectly.

so in general, how can I make it take into account the ones I selected in the select, (with AND) and not the ones I didn't?

the php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['list1']) || isset($_POST['list2']) || isset($_POST['list3']) || isset($_POST['vdate']) || isset($_POST['kdate']) || ) 
{
        
        $list1= $_POST['list1'];
        $list2= $_POST['list2'];
        $list3= $_POST['list3'];
        
        $kdate= $_POST['kdate'];
        $vdate= $_POST['vdate'];
            
            $query = "
select *
from table
where status = $list1 and day= '$list2' and city= '$list3'  and  datum BETWEEN '$kdate' and '$vdate'
order by date desc, idopont desc
" ;  

        $result = pg_query($query);
        $bg="";

        while($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
        {   
        
        
            echo "<tr $bg>";
            
            echo "<td>" .$row[0] ."</td>";  //0     
            echo "<td >" .$row[1] ."</td>"; //1
            echo "<td >" .$row[2] ."</td>"; 
            echo "<td >" .$row[3] . "</td>";
            echo "<td >" .$row[4] ."</td>"; 
            echo "<td >" .$row[5] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row[6] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row[7] ."</td>";
            echo "<td >" .$row[8] . "  </br> " .$row[15] . "</td>";
            echo "<td >" .$row[9] . "</td>";
            
            echo "<td>" .$row[10] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row[11] ."</td>";
            echo "<td >" .$row[12] . "</td>";
            echo "<td >" .$row[13] . "</td>";
            echo "<td >" .$row[14] . "</td>";
            
            echo "</tr>";
            
        }
```

}

Comment: How is your data structured? How are these values being used in your query?

Comment: Please can you share the PHP code you have, particularly the part that is assenbling your query?

Comment: The filters would filter the data of a table, referring to different attributes, for example, one would filter for the status, the other for the city, and the third for the time of day

Comment: I've added the php code

Comment: So for each of those, check if the value is _not_ `null`, and only then dynamically append a part for this to your query's WHERE clause. (Hint: If you start your WHERE clause with a non-condition like `... WHERE 1=1`, then you can append all your dynamic conditions with ` AND ...`)